# How do I target multiple files with HandBrakeCLI?

Tags: command-line, handbrake

How do I target multiple files (and or recursively through directories) with HandBrakeCLI like when using the GUI? When using the GUI with Mac I can select a folder with multiple files and queue the lot.

I guess I'm asking how do I queue with CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[With a script](http://www.davelachapelle.ca/guides/handbrake-cli-encoding/):

```
#!/bin/bash

# this script is to convert automatically a folder of video files to mp4
# You need to change SRC -- Sourse folder and DEST -- Destination folder
# The mp4 format is 480x270 

SRC=/home/$USER/Videos/
DEST=/home/$USER/Videos/mp4/
DEST_EXT=mp4
HANDBRAKE_CLI=HandBrakeCLI

for FILE in `ls $SRC`
do
        filename=$(basename $FILE)
        extension=${filename##*.}
        filename=${filename%.*}

        $HANDBRAKE_CLI -i $SRC/$FILE -o $DEST/$filename.$DEST_EXT -e x264 -q 22 -r 12 -B 64 -X 480 -O
done
```

Save, make it exectuable and this will convert files to .mp4 in directory /home/$USER/Videos to /home/$USER/Videos/mp4/. Change and create the dirs to what you need. And alter the line with $HANDBRAKE_CLI in to use your own parameters and setting.

Comment: I'm unable to test this as when I plug in my HDD it says its read only.

Comment: So mount it as read/write.

Comment: I followed instructions on another question for a command along the lines of "remount,rw" but it didn't work.

Comment: The HDD is journaled so it can't be written to :(

Comment: after 8 years, all is working greatly

Answer (score 0):

In a case if you'll need to add preset, it can be done in following way:

Change following line from @Rinzwind answer:
`$HANDBRAKE_CLI -i $SRC/$FILE -o $DEST/$filename.$DEST_EXT`

To this: `$HANDBRAKE_CLI -v --preset-import-file /Users/your_user/Desktop/my_preset.json -i $SRC/$FILE -o $DEST/$filename.$DEST_EXT`